# Show/Hide Div Jquery Mobile view issue Wordpress Divi

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, show, show-hide

I have a problem with a jquery code not running for the mobile menu in the mobile view.

```
        $("#section-intro").show();
        $("#section-about-us").hide();
        $("#section-what-we-do").hide();
        $("#section-oil-gas").hide();
        $("#section-infrastructure").hide();
        $("#section-mining").hide();
        $("#section-constructions").hide();
        $("#section-logistics").hide();
        $("#section-main-services").hide();
        $("#section-business-approach").hide();
        $("#section-resources").hide();
        $("#section-contact-us").hide();
        // Show chosen section from menu, and hide all others sections
        $('.hidecontent').click(function(){
            jQuery(".showHideDiv").hide();
            var id = $(this).attr("href");
            $(id).show();
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="65" data-fixed-height="40" style="padding-left: 238px;">
<nav id="top-menu-nav">
    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
        <li id="menu-item-46532" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46532"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-about-us">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46533" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46533"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-what-we-do">What we do</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46534" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-46534"><a href="#">Industries</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-46535" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46535"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-oil-gas">Oil &amp; Gas</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46536" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46536"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-infrastructure">Infrastructure</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46537" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46537"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-mining">Mining</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46604"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-constructions">Constructions</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46603"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-logistics">Logistics</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46538" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46538"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-main-services">Main services</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46539" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46539"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-business-approach">Business approach</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46541"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-resources">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46542"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-contact-us">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>




<div id="et_mobile_nav_menu">
    <div class="mobile_nav closed">
        <span class="select_page">Select Page</span>
        <span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
        <ul id="mobile_menu" class="et_mobile_menu">
            <li id="menu-item-46532" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46532 et_first_mobile_item"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-about-us">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46533" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46533"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-what-we-do">What we do</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46534" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-46534"><a href="#">Industries</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-46535" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46535"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-oil-gas">Oil &amp; Gas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46536" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46536"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-infrastructure">Infrastructure</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46537" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46537"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-mining">Mining</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46604"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-constructions">Constructions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46603"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-logistics">Logistics</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46538" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46538"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-main-services">Main services</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46539" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46539"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-business-approach">Business approach</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46541"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-resources">Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46542"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-contact-us">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works on desktop but when it goes to mobile menu, nothing. Also it dosn't prints anything in console on mobile.

I tried

alert(id);
console.log(id);

It alerts and adds in the logs but not on mobile, only desktop.

Who has an idea about this?

You can see live here: http://euro.greekmedia.ro

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The menu seems to be toggling fine in the mobile view.

Comment: The issue is that after the toggle and pressing a link from menu it should hide intro (let's say, as example) and if you click "contact" it should go to contact section. And it dosnt do that when it has to use toggle menu but on desktop works just fine. Do you have any idea?

Comment: But all the contact section seems to have `display:none` in the mobile view? You have hidden all the sections right

Comment: It's just jquery used, no css. Yes, i've hidden all sections by default and when i press a link it should show the one i click on.

Comment: Have you tried it as `jQuery(id).show();` instead of `$(id).show();` in the click event ?

Comment: Tried it now, same.

Answer (score 0):

So, i've got it working using:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".hidecontent").click(function(event) {
                jQuery(".showHideDiv").hide();
                var id = $(this).attr("href");
                $(id).show();
            });
        });
```

I'm so happy. Ufff.